# What are the disadvantages of actor-only methods with respect to value-based ones?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, comparison, policy-gradients, policy-based-methods, value-based-methods

While the advantages of actor-only algorithms, the ones that search directly the policy without the use of the value function, are clear (possibility of having a continuous action space, a stochastic policy, etc.), I can't figure out the disadvantages, if not general statements about less stability or bigger variance with respect to critic-only methods (with which I refer to methods that are based on the value function).